# How to generate 2x 3x images for atlas?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, retina-display

I have several animations, each one is about ~50 frames. When I'm adding atlas, it adds 1x only.

So, is there an easy way to batch generate 2x & 3x images, and add them to the project?

I've found the tools for 2x/3x images generation, but it would be really annoying to add every of ~200 frames (summary 400 with all variants) to project manually…

Comment: if you make the @2x and @3 images, you can drop them in with the original and it will automatically group it together for you

Comment: In general you want to work from larger size texture downwards (ie. scale down). When scaling a smaller image to a larger image, it will result in blockier looking images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the image size of 1X/2X/3X in this URL.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html

Note: A image (2X or 3X) you want, you can drag a image(1X, 2X or 3X) you want and drop into a suitable place (1X, 2X OR 3X).

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about dragging @2x/@3x.